# Samba Service Printer Does Not Execute

Tags: samba, printing

I installed a samba service on my `raspberry pi 3` linux: `Jessie (Debian 8)`.

### smb.conf

```
[global]
  netbios name = medicalexporter
  workgroup = WORKGROUP

  public = yes

  # Run a WINS server
  wins support = yes

  local master = yes
  preferred master = yes
  os level = 65

  log level = 10
  log file = /home/pi/logs/samba.log.%m

[SambaTest]
  comment = Samba-Test-Freigabe
  path = /home/pi/shares/test
  read only = no

[pdfCreatorLinux]
  path = /tmp
  printable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  print command = /usr/bin/printpdf %s
  lpq command =
  lprm command =
```

### /usr/bin/printpdf

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG_FILE=/home/pi/logs/pdf.log
exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
DATE="date +%b%d-%H%M%S"
OUTDIR=/home/pi/shr/pdfdropbox

"hello" >> /home/pi/logs/2.log
ps2pdf $1 \$OUTDIR/\$DATE.temp
mv \$OUTDIR/\$DATE.temp \$OUTDIR/\$DATE.pdf
rm \$1
```

For testing purposes I gave this script the permission `777` with `sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/printpdf`

### samba folder

```
mkdir -p ~/shr/pdfdropbox
chown root:root ~/shr/pdfdropbox
chmod u+rwx ~/shr/pdfdropbox
```

The samba service has a user and `smbd` & `nmbd` are running. I can see the samba service on my mac under `sharing` and access the sharing folder. I see the printer under my network printers. When I print a document via the samba printer, it shows me that it is connecting, sending the data and that the data is received without failure.

But the `/usr/bin/printpdf` seems not to be executed. There is nothing in the `/home/pi/logs` besides the logs from samba itself (two logs, one with the name of my computer and one with an ip).

When I start the pdf script manually the logs get created.

PS: I mostly sticked to that tutorial:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue72/bright.html

## Question

Why is the script not executed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line has an error:

`"hello" >> /home/pi/logs/2.log`

You may want to try

`echo "hello" >> /home/pi/logs/2.log`

And you are quoting the `$`s in the rest of script. I would try to remove the `\`s. And quote the full file names.

Ending up with:

```
echo "hello" >> /home/pi/logs/2.log
ps2pdf "$1" "$OUTDIR/$DATE.temp"
mv "$OUTDIR/$DATE.temp" "$OUTDIR/$DATE.pdf"
rm "$1"
```

in the second half of your script

Comment: You are right, it does not add the "hello" but the file ist still created empty when the script runs successfully. So this is not the reason the script is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

So I found multiple things. First I needed to add `printing = BSD` maybe otherwise CUPS is used which [overrides](https://books.google.de/books?id=MFgq3fx_doAC&pg=PA401&lpg=PA401&dq=samba+ignoring+print+command&source=bl&ots=Qpfzo1INIJ&sig=umwv9vSflgaGThf9bkLmpdkyI0c&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTud7v2L3NAhXFWRQKHW1SBOYQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=samba%20ignoring%20print%20command&f=false) settings. Then I needed to set `printcap name = /dev/null` otherwise the ghostscript files disappeared before I could access them. The `lpq` and `lpr` commands where not required.

```
[pdfCreatorLinux2]
#  load printers = no
  printcap name = /dev/null
  path = /tmp/
  printable = yes
  printing = BSD
  print command = /usr/bin/printpdf %s
#  lpq command =
#  lprm command =
```

Secondly all scripts and folders must be accessible to the user of the samba service.

PS: I also adjusted the pdf script, but this was not the reason why it was not executed.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG_FILE=/home/pi/logs/pdf.log
exec 3>&1 1>${LOG_FILE} 2>>&1
DATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
OUTDIR="/home/pi/shr/pdfdropbox"

ps2pdf $1 "$OUTDIR/$DATE.temp"
mv $OUTDIR/$DATE.temp $OUTDIR/$DATE.pdf
rm $1
```